# Error: ngModel:datefmt, Model is not a date object, Expected `yyyyMMdd` to be a date

Tags: angularjs

My model works fine with below code however it throws an error in console about wrong data type binding in model as input type is date. How can I instruct ensure that warning should not appear and value being bound is correct.
I want to show my model value as date and keep this as INT in my model. 
My model uses

```
$scope.start_date = "20170818";
```

HTML

```
<input type="date" Date-Converter ng-model="start_date" />
```

> Error: ngModel:datefmt Model is not a date object Expected `20170818`
>   to be a date

```
// Converts value parameter from yyyyMMdd into yyyy/MM/dd format and vice versa
app.directive('dateConverter', function($filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

            ngModel.$formatters.length=0;
            ngModel.$parsers.length=0;

            function fromUser(text) {
                var value = $filter('date')(text, "yyyyMMdd");                  
                return value;
            }

            function toUser(text) {             
                var value = new Date();
                if(text != undefined && text!='' && text.length==8){
                    var year        = text.substring(0,4);
                    var month       = text.substring(4,6);
                    var day         = text.substring(6,8);              
                    var value        = new Date(year, month-1, day);
                }
                return value;               
            }

            ngModel.$parsers.push(fromUser);
            ngModel.$formatters.push(toUser);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue should be related to this line of code:

```
var value = $filter('date')(text, "yyyyMMdd");
```

You are using the AngularJS date filter, but if you look in the official page, the first parameter of the method is the following:

> Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number)
>   or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats (e.g.
>   yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and its shorter versions like
>   yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ). If no timezone is
>   specified in the string input, the time is considered to be in the
>   local timezone.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

So you should provide the milliseconds, even if they are a string or int, but they should represent the millisecond, and not your date format as `20170818`.

So my suggestion is to keep your structure as it is, but before to call this line of code:

```
var value = $filter('date')(text, "yyyyMMdd");
```

you should convert your type into a valid date format. So for example something like:

```
var d = new Date(text.substring(0,4), text.substring(4,6), text.substring(6));
```

And then:

```
var value = $filter('date')(d, "yyyyMMdd");
```